4 column layout Center 3rd Column
I want a 4 column layout for a footer in HTML, with the logo- which is the third column - centered to the footer. So essentially the first two columns would be to the left of the logo, the logo centered, and the 4th column to the right of the logo. I know how to achieve this using a 3 column layout but I was wondering if there's a simpler way to achieve it using flex or grid and a 4 column layout.
Edit: I just thought of doing this, still wondering if there's a better way?


  .container {
      display: grid;
      justify-content: space-between;
      grid-template-columns: .5fr .5fr 1fr 1fr;
      justify-items: center;
    }
<footer>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="column">First Column</div>
      <div class="column">Second Column</div>
      <div class="center-column">Centered Column</div>
      <div class="column">Fourth Column</div>
    </div>
  </footer>




Maybe you can join the first and the second div into a wrapping div with grid layout as well( 2column) and then the container will have 3columns such as grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr

Use a nested grid. The outer grid has three columns, the first column of which contains a nested inner grid with two columns.


footer, .column-pair {
  display: grid;
  gap: 5px;
}

footer {
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, minmax(0, 1fr));
  text-align: center;
}

footer>* {
  border-bottom: 10px solid black;
  border-radius: 0 0 8px 8px;
}

.column-pair {
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, minmax(0, 1fr));
}

.column {
  padding: 3em 0;
}

.c1 {
  background: orange;
}

.c2 {
  background: pink;
}

.c3 {
  background: lime;
}

.c4 {
  background: cyan;
}
<footer>
  <div class="column-pair">
    <div class="column c1">First Column</div>
    <div class="column c2">Second Column</div>
  </div>
  <div class="column c3">Centered Column</div>
  <div class="column c4">Fourth Column</div>
</footer>



